# Refresh rate on flat screen VS refresh rate on cathodic screen

Tags: display, refresh-rate

With the cathodic screen, higher the refresh rate was the best for your eyes. I remember that 60 Hertz was always to low. I set it at higher as I could

Since I use a flat screen, I don't care about the refreshing rate because it seems I didn`t have to. I never have headache, problem with eyes...

This morning, I checked the refresh rate of my flat screen and it's 60 hertz. I can't set it to a higher rate.

Why 60 hertz is ok ( at least it seems ok for me...) on a flat screen and it was obviously to low on cathodic screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flickering on a CRT monitor came from the fact, that the whole picture was drawn by a single beam that had to move across the screen 60 (or more) times a second, creating each pixel. That meant that the pixels the beam was not hitting at the moment were already fading.

On an LCD monitor the pixels do not get turned off, but instead their color is adjusted on refresh. The update rate is typically 60Hz for a regular LCD display. For 3D displays, the refresh rate is 100Hz or even 200Hz. There are limits to how fast the pixels can change their color, but that does not produce flickering (motion blur instead). Only thing that can cause noticeable flicker on LCD screens is the backlight. However, the backlight is usually operating at around 200Hz [1].

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate#Computer_displays

Answer (score 1):

The underlying technology is 100% different.  You can buy 120hz or 144hz flat screen monitors, and even a few 240hz exist.  I have a 144hz asus monitor.  These monitors are considered **High end** so expect to pay a premium say $800-$900 for 27".